# SELECT a column from another table based on another table's value

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Ok so the title is bit of a mess, but I have a table `city` like this:

```
id | name     | population
1  | Bla bla  | 1323
2  | Blaer    | 35365
```

Now I'm selecting into one table from yet another table:

```
INSERT INTO tmp (
    name, age, city_id
)
SELECT
    NAME,
    AGE,
    CITY
FROM main;
```

The problem is the `SELECT CITY`, since `CITY` is the name of the city, but I need the `id`. So basically I want something like this, but this doesn't work:

```
INSERT INTO tmp (
    name, age, city_id
)
SELECT
    NAME,
    AGE,
    city.id FROM city WHERE city.name = CITY
FROM main;
```

Answer (score 1):

Do an `INNER JOIN` with the city table and use it in the select clause.

```
INSERT INTO tmp (
    name, age, city_id
)
SELECT
    NAME,
    AGE,
    c.id 
FROM main m
INNER JOIN city c on m.city=c.name ;
```

Answer (score 0):

It's bit unusual to find id from value. Why have you stored city in the main table? You should have stored city id there.

But a simple JOIN will do:

```
INSERT INTO tmp (name, age, city_id)
SELECT
    m.NAME,
    m.AGE,
    c.id
FROM main m join city c on m.city = c.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO tmp(
  name,
  age,
  city_id
)
SELECT 
  m.name AS name,
  m.age AS age,
  (SELECT c.id FROM city c WHERE c.name = m.city) AS city_id
FROM main m
```